# How to implement video chatting with html5?

Tags: flash, html, video-streaming

I've long heard that `html5` can replace `flash`.

Video chatting is not hard to implement in `flash`,

but how to implement it with `html5`?

Comment: This is too broad of a "question" to be answered here IMHO.

Comment: html5 just provides the canvas and a host of other technologies do the work

Comment: I think we are allowed broad questions on this site.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible because unlike Flash, HTML5 doesn't have native webcam support yet.

Try to take a look at thoses articles for more informations about HTML5 and Flash:

- [HTML5: The Facts And The Myths](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/09/23/html5-the-facts-and-the-myths/)
- [HTML5 And Flash: Why It’s Not A War, And Why Flash Won’t Die](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/05/18/html5-and-flash-why-its-not-a-war-and-why-flash-wont-die/)

[edit] And, if you are really interressted about using webcam with HTML5, keep an eye here:

- [Web Applications 1.0 - 4.11.6 The device element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/complete/commands.html#devices)

Comment: What other techniques will be involved to implement video chatting with html5?

Comment: I guess this doesn't work than? http://devworks.thinkdigit.com//Internet/Native-webcam-support-to-come-with-HTML5_3834.html

Comment: Is there a streaming server coupled with html video?You know,such a server is necessary if you are not just play it once,but saving it for playback in future.

Comment: @Mark Baijens: Follow the link given by this article (http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/complete/commands.html#devices). The device element have a mark "Idea; yet to be specified", and this document is a "Draft Standard" with "call for comment"...